# And another one bites the dust

Tags: no-computers, chess

I recently found an extraordinary moremover online today. Have fun finding the solution!

It’s White to move and mate in **19 moves!**

Bonus: Explain the title in relation to the solution!

**Jozef Lozek, Pat a Mat 27, December 1999**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it looks like

> 1. Bb7+ Kxb7
>  2. Bxc6+ Kc8
>  3. Bb7+ Kxb7
>  4. Bxd5+ Kc8
>  5. Bb7+ Kxb7
>  6. Bxe4+ Kc8
>  7. Bb7+ Kxb7
>  8. Bxf3+ Kc8
>  9. Bb7+ Kxb7
>  10. Bxg2+ Kc8
>  11. Bb7+ Kxb7
>  12. Qh1+ Kc8
>  13. Qa8+ Nb8
>  14. Qxb8+ Kd7
>  15. Qb5+ Kc8
>  16. Qa6+ Kd7
>  17. Qc6+ Kc8
>  18. Bxd6+ Qc7
>  19. Qxc7#

The title

> refers to all of the self sacrificing Bishops, I think.